# MFC: write text using stock font, but bold

Tags: mfc

This is an easy way to draw some text with a default font.

```
pDC->SelectObject(GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT));
pDC->SetTextColor(::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT));
pDC->DrawText(text, -1, rc, DT_LEFT | DT_SINGLELINE | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_VCENTER | DT_END_ELLIPSIS);
```

How can I do exactly the same, but in **bold** type... same font but **bold**? Can it be done without creating custom CFont object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CFont* pOldFont = pDC->GetCurrentFont();

LOGFONT logFont;
pOldFont->GetLogFont(&logFont);
logFont.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

CFont newFont;
newFont.CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);

pDC->SelectObject(&newFont);
pDC->DrawText();
pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
```

Comment: newFont.CreateFontIndirect(&old); --- should be &logFont? Also do I have to destroy this font when done?

Comment: Should be &logFont, yes. You don't have to destroy - the destructor will.

Answer (score 0):

Get the font data for the stock font into a LOGFONT struct (GetObject() in plain GDI). Change the weight parameter to bold. Use CreateFontIndirect() to make a font from that LOGFONT struct. Select the font into the device context.

Then draw the text as usual.