# Function to wrap setting the font weight on an MFC dialog control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a C++ class that derives from the MFC `CStatic` class, for displaying static text on MFC dialogs.  I want to add a method to that class that will let me choose the font weight.  I don't understand the relationship between CFonts and LOGFONTs, and when to create them and destroy them.  Here's my first attempt:

```
HRESULT CPVCtrlFontStatic2::SetWeight(long weight)
{
    // Get the control's current font
    CFont* pFont = GetFont();

    // Get a logical font object from the current font
    LOGFONT lf;
    pFont->GetLogFont(&lf);

    // Set the desired weight
    lf.lfWeight = weight;

    // Create a new font object
    pFont->CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

    // Tell the control to use the new font.
    SetFont(pFont);

    return S_OK;
}
```

When I run this, Windows crashes in the call to `CreateFontIndirect()` because the font object's `m_hObject` value is not `NULL`.  It seems I need to create a new `CFont` object.  But if I create it on the stack, it will disappear as soon as it goes out of scope, won't it?  Or will the fact that the control is using it keep it in memory?  If I create it dynamically using new, then I have to manage its lifetime, adding complication I don't want.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Look at the source of `SetFont`. What does it do with the parameter you give it? If it passes along the hfont member or keeps the pointer, you'll need to keep your object somewhere.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2064952/2287576

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/creating-a-logical-font

Comment: If you just need to set the font for all instances of your static controls (which is quite common, eg to achieve a consistent UI appearance for the app or part of the app ), the whole thing can be simplified a lot. The same font can be reused, ie you don't need one `HFONT`/`CFont`) for every instance of your control class, so it can be created during initialization and never be destroyed (the Windows Resource Manager will destroy when app exits). Also check the `DS_SETFONT` dialog style, it causes all controls of a dialog-box to use a specified (custom) font.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for `CFont`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfont-class?view=msvc-170#cfont) does not describe the destructor, but it almost certainly claims ownership of the `HFONT` that it contains and destroys it at that time.  So yes, you need to control the lifetime of that `CFont` object.

Put a `CFont` member object in your derived static class and use that.

```
// Create a new font object
m_font.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

// Tell the control to use the new font.
SetFont(&m_font);
```